# How much of the modern internet based on client server architecture?

Tags: internet

I have checked google, didn't find any feasible answer. There are more than 3.5 billion internet users in this world, I want to know how much of these users using the client-server model of the internet.

Comment: The Internet is based on IP, which is a network-layer protocol. There are no clients or servers at the network layer. Even transport layer protocols do not have clients or servers. The client/server concept is an application-layer concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vast majority is client server.

[Cisco Visual Networking Index](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/solutions/collateral/service-provider/visual-networking-index-vni/complete-white-paper-c11-481360.html) estimates in 2016 that there were was 96,054 PB per month global IP traffic, of which 5,376 PB per month, or about 6%, is peer to peer file sharing. Transfer is not a device count, but really when do you ever use a peer to peer architecture on a mobile device?

Within an application there might be varying approaches to connectivity like a message bus, but the end user probably uses some kind of client server model.

Answer (score 3):

73.6% of all statistics are made up on the spot. That seems like a reasonable figure too.

Comment: thanks for your response. But what's your proof of that claim? Could you provide me with any link to that stat?

Comment: .......and it just barely passes over his head!